# How to build kernel-debuginfo from upstream kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, rpm, linux-kernel, kernel-debugging

box: centos7.5 x86_64
from upstream:

tar xvfz linux-4.xx.xx

make menuconfig  ( set CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y)

save .config

make rpm-pkg

output 3 rpm:kernel-xxx, kernel-devel-xxx, src.rpm

but where is debuginfo and debuginfo-common rpm packages? How to generate it ?

I have been searching online for two days but still stuck!

Any tips?

Comment: Which Linux distribution, and which version? More than one of them use rpm.

Comment: centos7.5 @JohnMahowald